# Delete node from Firebase using React and firereact

Tags: javascript, firebase, reactjs

I'm pretty puzzled by the way reactfire works, as there doesn't seem to much about it documentation-wise.

So I want to delete and update some child nodes, but I have no idea how to do it. All tutorials focus solely in retrieving data, which are treated as a regular array and I don't even seem to get access to their keys.

Here's the official example: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-05-01-using-firebase-with-react.html

How do perform these operations using React?

Once you instantiate FB:

````
```
this.fb = new Firebase('https://react-testing.firebaseio.com/items');
this.bindAsArray(this.fb, 'items');
```
````

'items' becomes bound to this.state.items. Cool, now I have the data.

But how do I manipulate it? What's the correct way of getting a reference to the item being passed?

Comment: As you might have noticed, the ReactFire library is a tiny wrapper (135 lines, see https://github.com/firebase/reactfire/blob/master/src/reactfire.js around the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK and does not expose the full functionality. If you want to build an application with Firebase and React, you should invest the time to follow the regular Firebase guide: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/. With that knowledge, you'll be able to extend ReactFire to allow changes too.

Answer (score 4):

As I said in my comment: ReactFire is a tiny wrapper around *a small subset* of the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK. If you want to build an application beyond its capabilities, you can easily expand on it.

For your request I went ahead and changed the following snippet in ReactFire:

```
for (var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    out.push(obj[key]);
  }
}
```

To this:

```
for (var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var item = obj[key];
    item['$id'] = key;
    out.push(item);
  }
}
```

So we now pass the `key()` of each item as a "special" `$id` property of the item in the array.

With that I can expand the `TodoList3` class of the original to this:

```
var TodoList3 = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function(key) {
    if (this.props.onClick) {
      this.props.onClick(key);
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    var list = this;
    var createItem = function(item) {
      var boundClick = list.handleClick.bind(list, item['$id']);
      return <li key={ item['$id'] } onClick={boundClick}>{ item.text }</li>;
    };
    return <ul>{ this.props.items.map(createItem) }</ul>;
  }
});
```

So we now identify the Todo items by their `$id`/`key()`, instead of their index and use that value when the user clicks the item.

With that we can expand the JSX of TodoApp3 to pass in a handler for when the user clicks an item:

```
<TodoList3 items={ this.state.items } onClick={this.handleClick} />
```

And the app will then delete the item, by calling into the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK.

```
handleClick: function(key) {
  var firebaseRef = this.state.ref;
  firebaseRef.child(key).remove();
},
```

Links:

- [my modified ReactFire script](https://github.com/puf/reactfire/blob/puf-add-id-to-array-items/src/reactfire.js)
- [a fiddle showing the complete code in action](https://jsfiddle.net/s27nz1hb/)

Comment: Frank, thank you so much for your quick reply and updating the code, I can't thank you enough. Having an easy accessible key makes all the difference here (I found a hacky way of storing my own generated key in the item's attribute but it's obviously pretty unsafe) and this makes it so much easier. And yes, I'll spend some time properly learning the API too :) Cheers, Frank!